# Swift 2 For Loop with asynchronous network request continue looping after the response

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I'm trying to send a thousands of http request but my app is crashing due to memory issue. **"terminated due to memory issue"**. So I wanted to wait the response before continue looping to send another request.

```
for i in 0 ..< 10000 {

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { response in
        print("Finished request \(i)")
        // Continue the looping
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooo.... you want to make these requests synchronous?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do simple recursion as below.

```
func makeRequest(for index: Int) {
    guard index < 10000 else { return }
    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
        print("Finished request \(index)")
        self?.makeRequest(for: index + 1)
    }
}
```

and then start from zero or whatever index as below,

```
self.makeRequest(for: 0)
```